# What is the best way to manage message passing between multiple clients in real time chat?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, chat

I'm working on a real time chat application. I've build a basic chat app. But, I've some doubt whether I'm doing it right way or not ?

I'm using NODE JS + SOCKET IO for this. What I've done, whenever any client send any message to any other client.. that message comes to socket server & socket server just broadcast that message to all other connected clients with some additional details like for whom that message is for. So, at the client(browser) end when any right matches happen, it shows the message & It's working.

But my doubt at here is, is it a correct way to do ? Because, I'm broadcasting the message to all connected clients rather than the specific one's to whom it should go. Doesn't seems like a security risk ?

Then, rather than broadcasting that message to all clients, if i use socket id of recipient's & send that message to him/her only.. how i should manage situation like when one client connected with the service by different different devices like .. laptop,mobile,tab ? So that, when any message will come to him/her that message should be visible in all connected devices ?

Need some advice about best way to this.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should store user session(id, socket)

Server side:

```
 var clientSessions = []

// On connection
sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var user = new Object();
  user.id = socket.handshake.query.userId;
  user.socket = socket;
  clientSessions.push(user);
});
```

Client side:

```
 socketio.connect('http://localhost:3000', {query: 'userId=ABCXYZ'});
```

Comment: Yeah!!!, got your point. Would you tell me what'll should be the mechanism to handle when any client connected to the service from different devices like.. tab,mobile,laptop. 

What i think, for this i need to create an array for all users having different sessions info. So, when message will come to any specific user I've to check what are the different session(because of different devices) has been assign to that user & then again send that message to all those sessions. Am I right on this ?

Comment: After logging users need to be identified by a key information: id or username
A chat app, you should use a database (Redis) to store user session info

Answer (score -1):

You could store all the connections in an array or whatnot in the server, then determine which client you need to emit the message to when you need to send it to a single client.

Comment: So, you also agree with the thing that.. broadcasting message to all clients is not a good idea. It should be to specific one only through his/her socket id. Right ?

Comment: If you are sending data that should only be seen by the recipient, then yes broadcasting and client side filtering is a bad idea.

Comment: Ok, if i use recipient's socket id to send message then how i should handle the situation where client has connected from different devices like laptop, desktop, mobile, tab etc ?

Comment: You could store the with the socket id, their username or userid and send to any socket with the userid/name of who it needs to be sent to.

Comment: Would you tell me what'll should be the mechanism to handle when any client connected to the service from different devices like.. tab,mobile,laptop. What i think, for this i need to create an array for all users having different sessions info. So, when message will come to any specific user I've to check what are the different session(because of different devices) has been assign to that user & then again send that message to all those sessions. Am I right on this ?

Comment: You could create an array, then the array would have a list containing each user_id that is currently connected as a key, and the sockets that are associated along with it as an array value for that key->value pairing.

Comment: Oh man!!! It's means lot of task waiting for me. Ok, one more thing on which I've doubt is - Shall i keep all these user connected devices session info in NODEJS itself or i should store these info some where else like REDIS ? What's the best practice ? Because,  i think storing these in NODEJS will may make NODEJS heaver & working on these kind of data structure will not be easy on Javascript as compare to REDIS. What's your opinion ?

Comment: I got my answer. I think, I've to use redis for handling user's session. Any way, thanks a lot for helping me out.